# unable to access members of class during HTML web call

Tags: c#, rest

I'm having issues trying to access members of a class file inside of my foreach loop in a HTTP GET. in the past when I've done this I've been able to create the foreach loop and access the class file just to test pulling the data. but now when I enter d. I get none of my class members. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Class File:

```
class WhoIsOnCallParse : IEnumerable
    {
        public int CommonId { get; set; }
        public int DurationWorked { get; set; }
        public bool IsOnCall { get; set; }
        public int ScheduleRotationId { get; set; }
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        public int GroupRoleId { get; set; }
        public string CurrentMemberEndDate { get; set; }
        public string CurrentMemberStartDate { get; set; }
        public int RotationPosition { get; set; }
        public int Duration { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public bool IsRotation { get; set; }
        public int ScheduleOccurrenceId { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public int TeamMemberLeaderCommonId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }  
    }
```

Method for HTTP Call:

```
public void WhoIsOnCall()
        {
            DateTime dte = DateTime.Today;
            string fixedStartDate = String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd " + "05:00:00.000" + "}", dte);

            string URL = "http://oncall/api/GenerateRotation/mergedRotation/teamMemberOnCall/";
            string urlParameters = "?date=" + fixedStartDate + "Z&groupRoleId=1093&scheduleRotationId=1087";
            // string urlParameters = "?date=2017-04-21T18:55:15.194Z&groupRoleId=1093&scheduleRotationId=1087";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(URL);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(urlParameters).Result;  // Blocking call!
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Parse the response body. Blocking!
                var oncall = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<WhoIsOnCallParse>().Result;
                foreach (var d in oncall)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", d.);  //This is where my problem is.
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ehm... maybe a silly question, but where is your `GetEnumerator()` method in your `WhoIsOnCallParse` class?

Comment: considering I've never done this before that would probably be the answer. Thank you sir!